# WinForms C# app in Linux with Mono: Ends of labels are cut off (Autosizing issue?)

Tags: c#, linux, mono

Using a simple WinForms C# app as a test (just a form with some labels in it), compiled in Visual Studio on my Windows PC and then copied over to Linux to test out Mono. Using .NET 4.0

When I view the app on my RaspberryPi (Raspbian with Pixel desktop) with Mono, all functionality is fine (no errors or anything), but the ends of the labels are all cut off.

Example: For the label "This is a test," which looks fine on Windows, I only see "This is a" when run on the RasPi with Mono.

If I change the label's autosize property to false and manually make the label wider, then it works as expected - but that's a hassle for future development. I have tried changing the fonts to monospace font, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Is this a known issue with Mono? Is there a way to make the autosizing work correctly without having to manually adjust all of the labels to fixed widths?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a Windows font, use a Linux one, your app is probably confused by the Linux system substituting a different font to the one available on Windows.

Font substitution is widespread on Linux, and all substitutions do not use the same metrics.